# Reformulate in R log(Y+1)

Tags: r, formula

I am working on a data set where I have to generate formula to be passed to lm dynamically. So, I am using reformulate to do this.

```
formula = reformulate(termlabels = c('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'), response="y")
```

y is continuous.

This gets me the formula as `y ~ feature1+feature2+feature3`

However I want the formula to be `log(y+1) ~ feature1+feature2+feature3`

How do I do this using reformulate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass in the response as a quoted expression:

```
x <- c("feature1", "feature2", "feature3")
reformulate(x, response=quote(log(y+1)))
```

Or you could just construct the formula manually. This is what `reformulate` does under the hood.

```
formula(paste("log(y + 1) ~", paste(x, collapse="+")))
```

Comment: I would have guessed that `as.formula` would be used for the second strategy.

Comment: what if you use reformulate in a loop and need to do something such as log(var) , where var = dat[,i]? In this case, var is just an object standing in for the actual variable name (an therefoe the baove doesn't work).