# Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I am new to R and I want to improve the following script with an `*apply` function (I have read about `apply`, but I couldn't manage to use it). I want to use `lm` function on multiple independent variables (which are columns in a data frame). I used

```
for (i in (1:3) {
  assign(paste0('lm.',names(data[i])), lm(formula=formula(i),data=data))
  }
```

`Formula(i)` is defined as

```
formula=function(x)
{
  as.formula ( paste(names(data[x]),'~', paste0(names(data[-1:-3]), collapse = '+')), env=parent.frame() )
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I don't get you wrong, you are working with a dataset like this:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(30), y2 = rnorm(30), y3 = rnorm(30),
                  x1 = rnorm(30), x2 = rnorm(30), x3 = rnorm(30))
```

`x1`, `x2` and `x3` are covariates, and `y1`, `y2`, `y3` are three independent response. You are trying to fit three linear models:

```
y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3
y2 ~ x1 + x2 + x3
y3 ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

Currently you are using a loop through `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, fitting one model per time. You hope to speed the process up by replacing the `for` loop with `lapply`.

**You are on the wrong track.** `lm()` is an expensive operation. As long as your dataset is not small, the costs of `for` loop is negligible. Replacing `for` loop with `lapply` gives no performance gains.

Since you have the same RHS (right hand side of `~`) for all three models, model matrix is the same for three models. Therefore, QR factorization for all models need only be done once. `lm` allows this, and you can use:

```
fit <- lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat)
#Coefficients:
#             y1         y2         y3       
#(Intercept)  -0.081155   0.042049   0.007261
#x1           -0.037556   0.181407  -0.070109
#x2           -0.334067   0.223742   0.015100
#x3            0.057861  -0.075975  -0.099762
```

If you check `str(fit)`, you will see that this is not a list of three linear models; instead, it is a single linear model with a single `$qr` object, but with multiple LHS. So `$coefficients`, `$residuals` and `$fitted.values` are matrices. The resulting linear model has an additional "mlm" class besides the usual "lm" class. I created a special [mlm](/questions/tagged/mlm) tag collecting some questions on the theme, summarized by its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mlm/info).

If you have a lot more covariates, you can avoid typing or pasting formula by using `.`:

```
fit <- lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ ., data = dat)
#Coefficients:
#             y1         y2         y3       
#(Intercept)  -0.081155   0.042049   0.007261
#x1           -0.037556   0.181407  -0.070109
#x2           -0.334067   0.223742   0.015100
#x3            0.057861  -0.075975  -0.099762
```

**Caution:** Do not write

```
y1 + y2 + y3 ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

This will treat `y = y1 + y2 + y3` as a single response. Use `cbind()`.

---

### Follow-up:

> I am interested in a generalization. I have a data frame `df`, where first `n` columns are dependent variables `(y1,y2,y3,....)` and next `m` columns are independent variables `(x1+x2+x3+....)`. For `n = 3` and `m = 3` it is `fit <- lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ ., data = dat))`. But how to do this automatically, by using the structure of the `df`. I mean something like `(for i in (1:n)) fit <- lm(cbind(df[something] ~ df[something], data = dat))`. That "something" I have created it with `paste` and `paste0`. Thank you.

So you are programming your formula, or want to dynamically generate / construct model formulae in the loop. There are many ways to do this, and many Stack Overflow questions are about this. There are commonly two approaches:

1. [use `reformulate`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12967797/4891738);
2. use `paste` / `paste0` and `formula` / `as.formula`.

I prefer to `reformulate` for its neatness, however, it does not support multiple LHS in the formula. [It also needs some special treatment if you want to transform the LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26374106/4891738). So In the following I would use `paste` solution.

For you data frame `df`, you may do

```
paste0("cbind(", paste(names(df)[1:n], collapse = ", "), ")", " ~ .")
```

A more nice-looking way is to use `sprintf` and `toString` to construct the LHS:

```
sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ .", toString(names(df)[1:n]))
```

Here is an example using `iris` dataset:

```
string_formula <- sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ .", toString(names(iris)[1:2]))
# "cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ ."
```

You can pass this string formula to `lm`, as `lm` will automatically coerce it into formula class. Or you may do the coercion yourself using `formula` (or `as.formula`):

```
formula(string_formula)
# cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ .
```

**Remark:**

This multiple LHS formula is also supported elsewhere in R core:

- [the formula method for function `aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41075121/4891738);
- [ANOVA analysis with `aov`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51937380/4891738).

Comment: I should stress that `glm` can't do multiple LHS. A GLM iteratively fits re-weighted linear regression, where the weights depend on the response variable. Obviously two different LHS would give two different sets of weights, hence two different weighted model matrices. It is then impossible to do a common QR factorization. A very similar scenario is [Run lm with multiple responses and weights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15296833/4891738).