# How can I save my multiple lm summary output to a data frame or csv?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, lm, mlm

I am trying to save the summary outputs of a `lm` into a data frame, "csv" or "txt" file. What I wanted to do is to use a `lm` (and eventually `glm`) with different dependent variables, but the same independent variables.

This is my code using `lapply` for model fitting:

```
varlist <- names(NDVI)[2:244]

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
lm(substitute(i ~ efectohuracan, list(i = as.name(x))), data = NDVI)})
```

If I save it as

```
write.csv(models,"models.csv")
```

I get this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = 
stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class ""lm"" to a data.frame
```

I am very new in R. The code I made it thanks to people who has posted their problems also in this community, so maybe there are better ways to approach this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I wrongly closed this as a dupe at the beginning. Thanks to my friend for reopening it.

---

For `"mlm"` model class this is very efficient.

First, you need to [Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262534/4891738)

Then let `fit` be your fitted model object (of `"mlm"` and `"lm"` class), extract its coefficients by

```
beta <- coef(summary(fit))
```

This is a list of coefficient tables.

Then, let's collapse it into a data frame:

```
tab <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, beta)
```

Now you just write this data frame into a "csv" file as usual.

As a quick test, you can use the toy dataset provided in the linked thread.