# ANOVA on R with different dependent variables

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I know so far how to run a ANOVA on R, but I allways have to duplicate the code to run de ANOVA for another variable, I was wondering if I could pass it somehow to the aov() in a loop the names of the variables and store the result of the ANOVA in variables so I don't have to manually change them by copying the code block.

E.G.:

Variables I want to test: Z, Y, X

Categorical Variable: Treatment

VectorVariables = c(Z, Y, X)

```
for (i in Vector) {
   AnovaZ <- aov(Z ~ Treatment) #then
   AnovaY <- aov(Y ~ Treatment) # and so on..

}
```

It is possible in some way??

Comment: You should probably read this: [Fast post hoc computation using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51937380/4891738)

Comment: @李哲源 I vote to re-open because (in my opinion) OP's question is not (directly) about post-hoc tests. At this point in time OP is asking about how to perform ANOVAs for different response variables in an efficient manner. Post-hoc tests address the issue with increased type I errors due to multiple testing. This may be related, but is not what OP is asking.

Comment: @李哲源 OP doesn't mention any post-hoc tests (such as e.g. `TukeyHSD`), so I'm not sure what he's planning to do after the ANOVAs. I don't see any "maov" references either. Perhaps OP should clarify. I was under the impression that he simply wants to perform two independent ANOVAs. A post-hoc test is only relevant for controlling the overall false-positive error rate in a single study involving multiple tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a `for` loop! You can simply `cbind` different response variables together.

Here is an example:

1. Since you don't provide a sample dataset, I generate some sample data based on the `npk` dataset, where I add a second response variable `yield2` which is the same as `yield` with some added white noise.

   ```
   set.seed(2018)
   df <- npk
   df$yield2 <- df$yield + rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 5)
   ```
2. Perform ANOVAs based on the two response variables `yield` and `yield2`

   ```
   res <- aov(cbind(yield, yield2) ~ block, df)
   #Call:
   #   aov(formula = cbind(yield, yield2) ~ block, data = df)
   #
   #Terms:
   #                   block Residuals
   #resp 1           343.295   533.070
   #resp 2          905.0327  847.2597
   #Deg. of Freedom        5        18
   #
   #Residual standard errors: 5.441967 6.860757
   #Estimated effects may be unbalanced
   ```

   `resp 1` and `resp 2` give the sum of squares that you get if you had run `aov(yield ~ block, df)` and `aov(yield2 ~ block, df)` individually.

So in your case, the command would be something like

```
res <- aov(cbind(Y, Z) ~ Treatment)
```

---

Or if you want to run and store results from separate ANOVAs, store the response variables in a `list` and use `lapply`:

```
lapply(list(Y = "Y", Z = "Z"), function(x)
    aov(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ Treatment", x)), df))
```

This produces a `list` of ANOVA results, where every `list` element corresponds to a response variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a loop, the trick is to use `as.formula(paste())`.

Create a list (we'll call it `result`) to store each `aov` output.  Then loop through dependent variable names stored in `Vector`:

```
n <- length(Vector)
result <- vector(mode="list", length=n)
for(i in 1:n) {
    result[[i]] <- aov(as.formula(paste(Vector[i], "~ Treament")))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use list columns and purrr::map. This can be useful when working with many models (e.g. see http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).

```
library(tidyverse)

aov_f <- function(df) {aov(value ~ carb, data = df)}

mtcars_n <- gather(mtcars, obs, value, mpg:gear) %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(aov = map(data, aov_f))
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, I will look at it!